# ARCore ApiTrackableTypeExtensions.cs error after updating ARCore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am updating my project from ARCore 1.2 (pretty sure) to 1.6. I imported the most up to date unity package for ARCore (1.6) and I am getting the following error in the console:

> Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Api/ApiTrackableTypeExtensions.cs(31,40):
>   error CS0050: Inconsistent accessibility: return type
>   GoogleARCoreInternal.ApiTrackableType' is less accessible than method
>   GoogleARCoreInternal.ApiTrackableTypeExtensions.GetApiTrackableType(this
>   Type)'

I am not sure how to resolve this. The Visual Studio 'quick fix' is not helpful in this case. I have tried reimporting ARCore 1.6 but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that was a leftover file. Removing the /scripts/API folder and then reimporting it updated that folder and fixed the error.